# How does scanCallback work for BluetoothDevices?

Tags: android, callback, bluetooth

I am following this tutorial. https://medium.com/@avigezerit/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-22bc7310387a

Trying to understand LeScancallBacks

I am also following the documentation and the sample for Bluetooth devices from google

```
BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback scanCallback =
                new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {};

  bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(scanCallback);

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
        byte[] scanRecord) {
            if(device.address == HR_SENSOR_ADDRESS){
                myDevice = device;
            }
        }
```

My Code gives me the following error:

> "Class 'Anonymous class derived from LeScanCallback' must either be
>   declared abstract or implement abstract method
>   'onLeScan(BluetoothDevice, int, byte[])' in 'LeScanCallback'"

When I compare it with the code from google.

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }
```

This is the only other Callback I can find, is it possible that someone can help? I tried to program this project, alone for some time.

Answer (score 1):

When you define that `scanCallback` object, you need to add in the required method like so:

```
    BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback scanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                //do stuff here
            }
    };
```

You can then handle the response in that `onLeScan` method.

In Java, an `abstract` class requires that any instantiation of it must implement the required methods, which is the error you were getting.